# Does Python have String Comprehension like List Comprehension?

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension

Does Python have a construct analogue to [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for creating strings, a "string comprehension"?

The task I need to do is remove all punctuation from the string.

```
def remove_punctuation(text: str) -> str:
    punctuations = [",", ".", "!", "?"]
    # next line is what I want to do
    result = text.replace(p, "") for p in punctuations
    return result

assert remove_punctuation("A! Lion?is. crying!..") == "A Lion is crying"
```

Comment: Yes, and no. Strings are sequences, so you can use them in list comprehensions, but the result is always a list (or a generator, for generator expressions). You must convert it to a string using `.join()` or some other method.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't string comprehension, however you can use generator expression, which is used in list comprehension, inside `join()`

```
text = ''.join(x for x in text if x not in punctuations)
print(text) # A Lion is crying
```

Comment: Small correction: What you have inside parentheses is a generator expression, not a list comprehension.

Answer (score 4):

Python already has a complete set of punctuations in the standard library.

`from string import punctuation`

`punctuation` returns strings !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~.

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html)

So you can create a list from your given input which checks whether or not each characters from your input is in the `punctuation` string.

```py
>>> [char for char in text if char not in punctuation]
['A', ' ', 'L', 'i', 'o', 'n', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'c', 'r', 'y', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

You can pass the resulting list in the built-in `str.join` method.

```py
>>> "".join([char for char in text if char not in punctuation])
'A Lion is crying'
```